# Tkinter label text not updating, label is visible and text value is up to date

Tags: python, tkinter, text, label

When trying to display text overtime on the tkinter window through a button press, the label does not update correctly. After testing multiple different scenarios, the label is classified as visible, the text value for it is correct, the function itself works without a button press and no matter if using pack, grid or place the result is the same. No matter how the label is updated, it is never displayed on the screen, but only if the button calls the function. When the button is pressed, it runs through the function, printing out everything along the way, and therefore the button itself is also working. Code below:

```
    def label_change(self, text):
    """ Repeats f|char_show (with a pause) until <text> equals the label text.

    Parameters:
        text (str): The text displayed in the label.
    """
    if self.last_txt == text:
        pass

    def char_show():
        """ Adds the next single character of <text> to the label text.

        Curtosy of Hritik Bhat on:
        stackoverflow.com/questions/56684556/how-to-have-variable-text-in-a-label-in-tkinter
        """

        if self.label_store == "":
            self.label_index = 0

        self.label_store += text[self.label_index]
        print(self.label_index)
        self.label_index += 1

        self.display.place_forget()
        self.display.config(text=self.label_store)
        self.display.update()
        self.display.place()

        print(self.display.cget("text"))
        self.display.update_idletasks()
        self.label_change(self.txt)
```

Comment: how do you use it? I don't see any button to run it. Create minimal working code so we could run it.

Comment: if you need to add char to label with some delay then use `root.after(time_ms, function_name)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add char with delay then you could use `root.after(time_ms, function_name)` to execute function with delay. This doesn't stops `mainloop()` and it doesn't need `update()` and `update_idletask()

```
import tkinter as tk

def start():
    global label_index

    # add next char to label
    display['text'] += text[label_index]
    label_index += 1

    # check if there is need to run it again
    if label_index < len(text):
        # run again after 200ms
        root.after(200, start)

# ---

text = 'Hello World'
label_index = 0

root = tk.Tk()

display = tk.Label(root)
display.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** this version blocks button when it updates label. It also reset settings when it starts animation again.

import tkinter as tk

```
def add_char():
    global label_index
    global running

    # add next char to label
    display['text'] += text[label_index]
    label_index += 1

    # check if there is need to run it again
    if label_index < len(text):
        # run again after 200ms
        root.after(200, add_char)
    else:
        # unblock button after end
        running = False

def start():
    global label_index
    global running

    # check if animation is running
    if not running:
        # block button
        running = True

        # reset settings
        display['text'] = ''
        label_index = 0

        # run animation
        add_char()

# ---

text = 'Hello World'
label_index = 0
running = False

root = tk.Tk()

display = tk.Label(root)
display.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=start)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```